# Ranking the Resulting Values of Measures in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, ranking, ranking-functions, kpi

Please help.

I am trying to create a dashboard (one-page) that shows KPIs of multiple groups. There are 10 groups and each group is represented with a box and the box is showing the group's %Compliance. Now, I want to add the RANK of this group's calculated measure Compliance (Format: Percentage) among the calculated measure Compliances of the 10 groups. See the syntax samples for the Compliance of each group.

ComplianceA = DIVIDE([CompletedA],[TotalA])

ComplianceB = DIVIDE([CompletedB],[TotalB])

ComplianceC = DIVIDE([CompletedC],[TotalC])

ComplianceD = DIVIDE([CompletedD],[TotalD])

. . .

All these measures are stored in one Table called RANKING.

I tried the RANKX function,

RANK GROUPA = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(RANKING),[ComplianceA])

RANK GROUPB = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(RANKING),[ComplianceB])

The results are all 1.

Can I rank the resulting values in measures?

Comment: Can you show your sample data and your expected output?

Comment: how? i have the sample file here. it's 617kb only. should i send it to you? how? I'm sorry, i'm new here. i'm still finding my way.

Comment: If you want to share a file, you can upload the file somewhere (e.g. Goolge Drive or Dropbox) and edit your question to include a link to the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I found the formula on the web. I just need to modify the formula a little bit to customize it to my own table and measure names.

RANKING = RANKX(ALL(Table[Group]),CALCULATE(SUMX(PRMD,[Compliance])))

You can view the final result in my LinkedIn.

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/ciriaco-espino_i-recreated-my-ms-excel-dashboard-in-power-activity-6742056358167814144-H5d1

Thanks to mkRabbani and Mr. Alexis Olson for their time. Your replies encouraged me to find and search the web for the solution. I really appreciate your replies. Thanks.